# Auto export e-mails from Outlook to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've found in the internet and modified a bit a piece of code:

```
Public WithEvents objMails As Outlook.Items 

Private Sub Application_Startup() 
Const pierwszy = "pierwszy@gmail.com" 
Const drugi = "drugi@gmail.com" 
Dim OutAcc As Account 
Debug.Print "Startup" 
    For Each OutAcc In Outlook.Application.Session.Accounts 
        If (OutAcc.DisplayName = pierwszy) Then 
            Set objMails = OutAcc.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items 
            Exit For 
        End If 
        If (OutAcc.DisplayName = drugi) Then 
            Set objMails = OutAcc.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items 
            Exit For 
        End If 
    Next 
End Sub 


Private Sub objMails_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) 
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
    Dim strExcelFile As String 
    Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application 
    Dim objExcelWorkBook As Excel.Workbook 
    Dim objExcelWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet 
    Dim nNextEmptyRow As Integer 
    Dim strColumnB As String 
    Dim strColumnC As String 
    Dim strColumnD As String 
    Dim strColumnE As String 

    If Item.Class = olMail Then 
       Set objMail = Item 
    End If 

    'Specify the Excel file which you want to auto export the email list 
    'You can change it as per your case 
    strExcelFile = "C:\Users\karol\Documents\test.xlsx" 

    'Get Access to the Excel file 
    On Error Resume Next 
    Set objExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 
    If Error <> 0 Then 
       Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
    End If 
    Set objExcelWorkBook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(strExcelFile) 
    Set objExcelWorkSheet = objExcelWorkBook.Sheets("Arkusz1") 

    'Get the next empty row in the Excel worksheet 
    nNextEmptyRow = objExcelWorkSheet.Range("B" & objExcelWorkSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 

    'Specify the corresponding values in the different columns 
    strColumnB = objMail.SenderName 
    strColumnC = objMail.SenderEmailAddress 
    strColumnD = objMail.Subject 
    strColumnE = objMail.ReceivedTime 
    strColumnF = objMail.Body 
    strColumnG = objMail.To 

    'Add the vaules into the columns 
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("A" & nNextEmptyRow) = nNextEmptyRow - 1 
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("B" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnB 
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("C" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnC 
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("D" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnD 
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("E" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnE 
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("F" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnF 
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("G" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnG 

    'Fit the columns from A to E 
    objExcelWorkSheet.Columns("A:G").AutoFit 

    'Save the changes and close the Excel file 
    objExcelWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=True 

End Sub
```

This code works fine, when in Outlook application I am logged in at one mailbox (one e-mail). I've faced a problem when I am trying to automatically export emails from two mailboxes (two accounts with different email addresses on which I am logged in to the Outlook application) - look at the picture:

https://ibb.co/mXWZJsw

I tried to solve this problem by using If statements in the Application_Startup () procedure (as seen in the code above). This approach, unfortunately, does not work. I also noticed that, for example, when the first email arrives at the account "pierwszy@gmail.com", then until the application is closed, emails will be exported to Excel only from this account "pierwszy@gmail.com" and not exported from the account "drugi@gmail.com". However, when the first e-mail arrives at the account "drugi@gmail.com", then emails will be exported from the seccond e-mail "drugi@gmail.com" until application is closed.

Comment: It's strongly recommended that you replace the email addresses in your post with fake stand-ins to avoid them getting inundated with spam from search crawlers.

Comment: @TylerH They are fake. pierwszy=first, drugi=second

Comment: @Dharman You don't think someone has registered those email addresses with Google? :-) When I say fake stand-ins I mean things that would not deliverable as an email address. This would also serve the purpose of not getting flagged by SmokeDetector as a bad string.

Comment: Please use the Tool in the site's editor to insert pictures that can be integrated into the question. Links to outside sources are disallowed - all information relevant to a question needs to be in the question, itself. Outside links can become invalid, making the question not useful for future site users.

Comment: Have you tried making a rule that links to vba code as opposed to initializing during startup? You can setup a new rule with the only requirement being "on this computer only" to "run a script". The script would take a MailItem as the passed variable and you can trigger the code based on this mail item. I can give an example if you'd like.

Comment: I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying - not sure how rules work for multiple accounts. You may need to create the rule for BOTH accounts but they can both reference the same script.

I've updated your code to be a public `Sub` vs `Private Sub` and placed it in a module so that it can be referenced by the rules engine.

[image]

Now, once we have the code in place (scripts run by Rules engine typically inherently pass the email as a MailItem to the sub and ByVal was causing issues with recognizing the script as one to be run from a MailItem so i updated it to `Item as MailItem`).

We next create a new rule using the rules engine. If you see this simplistic interface, click on Advanced Options. That will allow us to apply to rule to all emails.  In the advanced options window, do not check any box for `Which conditions do you want to check?` simply click Next. It will confirm you want to add this rule for ALL EMAILS which we do.

[image]

[image]

After selecting `run a script` we can click on `a script` to indicate which script we want to run. I set it to the exportToExcel script in Module(Project)1

[image]

Click Finish and test it out.

```
Sub exportToExcel(item As MailItem)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strExcelFile As String
    Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objExcelWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objExcelWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim nNextEmptyRow As Integer
    Dim strColumnB As String
    Dim strColumnC As String
    Dim strColumnD As String
    Dim strColumnE As String

    If item.Class = olMail Then
       Set objMail = item
    End If

    'Specify the Excel file which you want to auto export the email list
    'You can change it as per your case
    strExcelFile = "C:\Users\karol\Documents\test.xlsx"

    'Get Access to the Excel file
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Error <> 0 Then
       Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Set objExcelWorkBook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(strExcelFile)
    Set objExcelWorkSheet = objExcelWorkBook.Sheets("Arkusz1")

    'Get the next empty row in the Excel worksheet
    nNextEmptyRow = objExcelWorkSheet.Range("B" & objExcelWorkSheet.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Specify the corresponding values in the different columns
    strColumnB = objMail.SenderName
    strColumnC = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
    strColumnD = objMail.Subject
    strColumnE = objMail.ReceivedTime
    strColumnF = objMail.Body
    strColumnG = objMail.To

    'Add the vaules into the columns
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("A" & nNextEmptyRow) = nNextEmptyRow - 1
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("B" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnB
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("C" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnC
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("D" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnD
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("E" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnE
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("F" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnF
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("G" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnG

    'Fit the columns from A to E
    objExcelWorkSheet.Columns("A:G").AutoFit

    'Save the changes and close the Excel file
    objExcelWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: This trips many `Sub exportToExcel(item As Object)` rather than `Sub exportToExcel(item As MailItem)`.

Comment: Are you referring to mistakenly sending something besides a MailItem to this script?  If using the method I indicate with the rules engine, the only scripts that will appear in the list to run will be scripts that accept MailItem as an object

Comment: I stand corrected. Was tripped myself by the ` If item.Class = olMail Then`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did everything what you said but it still doesn't work for two accounts :|

Comment: Does the code trigger at all? Did you set up the rule for BOTH accounts?

Comment: Yes, I set up the rule for both accounts and still code works for only 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor multiple folders with ItemAdd.

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents objMailspierwszy As Items
Public WithEvents objMailsdrugi As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Const pierwszy = "pierwszy@somewhere.com"
    Const drugi = "drugi@somewhere.com"

    Dim OutAcc As Account

    For Each OutAcc In Session.Accounts

        Debug.Print "OutAcc.DisplayName: " & OutAcc.DisplayName
        Debug.Print "OutAcc.DeliveryStore: " & OutAcc.DeliveryStore

        If OutAcc.DisplayName = pierwszy Then

            Debug.Print "OutAcc.DisplayName: " & OutAcc.DisplayName

            Set objMailspierwszy = OutAcc.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
            Debug.Print "Listener on " & objMailspierwszy.Parent & " of DeliveryStore " & OutAcc.DeliveryStore

        End If

        If OutAcc.DisplayName = drugi Then

            Debug.Print "OutAcc.DisplayName: " & OutAcc.DisplayName

            Set objMailsdrugi = OutAcc.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
            Debug.Print "Listener on " & objMailspierwszy.Parent & " of DeliveryStore " & OutAcc.DeliveryStore

        End If

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub objMailspierwszy_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
'...
End Sub

Private Sub objMailsdrug_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
'...
End Sub
```